# Ubuntu 17.10 two monitors different resolution on Dell XPS 13 from 2015

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, wayland, 17.10

I just upgrade from Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 to 17.10, I have 2 monitors, the laptop that have a max resolution of 3200x1800 and a the secondary that have a max resolution of 1920x1080.

In other ubuntu versions I was unable to match this 2 resolutions, so my solution was to change the laptop resolution to 1920x1080 and it works.

But with this new update I'm unable to change the laptop resolution very time I try I get logged out from the session and when I enter again I have the same 3200x1080 resolution, I test this with Xorg and wayland.

Comment: What's your question? What are you trying to achieve? Could you please [edit] your question to add the output of `xrandr` to it (in an X.org session)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using [arandr](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/arandr-a-simple-visual-front-end-for-xrandr.html) (Graphical interface for xrandr) you can do it easily.

1) You need to install it:

`sudo apt install arandr`

2) Configure your schema:
[image]

3) Save your schema (it will saved into `~/.screenlayout` folder).

4) If *arandr* couldn't set 1920x1080 for you, open the file you saved (use gedit, nano or other text-based editor to change values. Do it and save;

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1280x1024 --pos 1920x0 --rotate left --output DVI-D-1-1 --off --output VGA-1-1 --off --output DVI-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-0 --off
```

5) Add this script to `~/.config/autostart/arandr.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=arandr.desktop
GenericName="Monitor Schema"
Comment="Script to automatic set resolution"
Exec=/home/<user>/.screenlayout/<file>.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-Gnome-Autostart=true
```

6) `chmod +x ~/.config/autostart/arandr.desktop` to enable it to be executed.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un9sM.png
```